# Mysterious line breaks in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I keep running into this weird behaviour of InDesign which probably has a simple solution.

Whenever I work with large text, I start getting weird line breaks inside the text. The example below is *one line* and does not contain a line break. It keeps breaking at the same position:

[image]

The text behaves as if there were an object in the center that forces the text to flow around it. But there is nothing. The page contains nothing but the background bitmap, and several text elements that are not interfering with each other.

What could this be?

I've already played with the "Adobe Paragraph Composer" settings outlined [here](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/situational-typography/typesetting-mysteries), to no avail.

Comment: I managed to control the behaviour by selecting "No line breaks" in the "Character" panel but I still don't understand what is bringing it about.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with another font?

Comment: @Cai yes! Just checked.

Comment: The weird alignment is confusing me a bit.. Is it meant to be left aligned or centered? If you turn on show hidden characters is there anything else in-between the 'denen' and 'es'?

Comment: @Cai nope, no hidden characters. It's meant to be centered, but shows weird behaviour also when left aligned. It must have to do with the document, though - when I start a completely new document, it doesn't happen

Comment: Unlikely to be an ID issue, most likely a document issue. Possibly a hidden object that could force the text to wrap, a baseline grid setting that could force the text to jump between different lines, or who knows what font error.

Comment: Invisible tab... negative line indentation.... could be any number of things. Does this happen if you create a brand new text box... and type brand new text?

Comment: Could be an item with text wrap is located on the document. You can test by selecting the text box, get Text Frame Options (Command/Control B) and selecting Ignore Text Wrap, to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your text frame is slightly skewed. This, combined with indent settings can cause exactly what you're experiencing. Look along the edge of the frame in your image. See how the frame edge (light blue like) isn't square to the boundary box (darker blue)? Put the text into a regular rectangular frame and see if the problem persists. (You can also select your text frame, then select Object>Convert to Shape>Rectangle.)
[image: Unintentional Line Break]